# Login to Facebook from another application

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have a windows application. Users will login to my windows application. Once logged in, there will be a button as "Login to Facebook". The logged in users username and password for facebook is already stored in my DB and i can retrieve that information.

What I need is, once the user clicks on the "Login to Facebook" button, it should automatically go to facebook page with the User logged in by providing the Username and Password retrieved from my DB.

If this is not do-able, upon clicking the button, it should open the facebook login page and enter the Username and Password values retrieved from DB in their relevant textboxes.

This is a research project for my studies. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Storing a user's Facebook username and password is a direct violation of the Facebook TOS.

Comment: And because it is not allowed it is also not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the following to understand the facebook's login flow
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

For manualy building the login flow go through this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login